# How do I load a webview in iBooks using Swift

Tags: webview, download, ibooks

**How do I load a webview in iBooks using Swift?**

I know this question has already been answered. But I can't find the complete answer. If somebody can tell me the complete answer theat would greatfull.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the question has already been answered, you should write a comment on the relevant answers to the question to ask for clarification rather than asking in a new question. At least post a link to the original question(s) if nothing else.

Comment: ok the link of the question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631293/how-do-i-load-a-webview-page-with-a-pdf-into-ibooks-using-swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631293/how-do-i-load-a-webview-page-with-a-pdf-into-ibooks-using-swift)